# Electro-Mechanical Connection: from screw straight up to electrical-wire?

Tags: connector, wire, mechanical

I am developing a system that includes aircraft cables with [threaded studs](http://en.ben-mor.com/ben-mor-threaded-studs-bm21259) - screw endings that are used for mounting. Here is a picture of the stud connected to a cable:

[image]

Now I am searching for an elegant solution to make the electrical connection to the screw. I am looking for connectors that would allow to go straight up from the screw ending
(instead of sideways with ring/spade terminals). Basically I am looking for a nut-wire connector. Ideally something that would help with isolating the whole connection, while still looking *pretty* as it will be visible.

Anyone aware of such a product? We are calling it the 'magic nut' here and we are still hoping it will pop up from somewhere! :)

Any tips, comments would be very helpful!

Answer (score 3):

You are likely to get some good ideas [here](http://www.google.co.nz/search?q=lbc817-40&hl=en&safe=off&prmd=imvns&source=lnms&tbm=isch&ei=gWBGT_TfKObRmAXdtNSnDg&sa=X&oi=mode_link&ct=mode&cd=2&ved=0CAwQ_AUoATge&biw=2133&bih=1201#hl=en&safe=off&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=threaded+stud+adapter&pbx=1&oq=threaded+stud&aq=7S&aqi=g1g-m1g-S8&aql=&gs_sm=1&gs_upl=1757l7512l0l13776l21l17l0l0l0l1l560l3645l2-13.5-1l15l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=e8effc80b31535b2&biw=2133&bih=1201) -  all images connect to a related webpage.

Something like [these adapters](http://studio-lighting.co.nz/14-and-38-female-threaded-screw-adapter-spigot-stud-p-160.html)  would allow you to connect two threaded studs together which should meet your need.

[image]

[This arrangement is similar](http://www.standsandmounts.com/images/products/detail/ACC810B.jpg) - tube with both ends threaded.

Something [like this](http://www.google.co.nz/imgres?q=threaded+stud+adapter&hl=en&safe=off&biw=1920&bih=1081&tbm=isch&tbnid=vHj4X0fv7b3vdM:&imgrefurl=http://flashzebra.com/products/0085/index.shtml&docid=c7hiAIEPA-6SWM&imgurl=http://flashzebra.com/products/0085/0085.jpg&w=600&h=404&ei=7mVGT9_IOJHJmAXL27GTDg&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=189&vpy=492&dur=3086&hovh=184&hovw=274&tx=178&ty=83&sig=105250506097979753968&page=3&tbnh=143&tbnw=212&start=112&ndsp=50&ved=1t:429,r:16,s:112) can have the cable from above entering from the opposite end to the stud (black as shown here, but with an end that is wider than the exit hole so it cannot escape. The stud is screwed in from the other and and tightens against the broad end of the cable.

[image]

Items [like these](http://studio-lighting.co.nz/14in-to-38in-tripod-monopod-convert-screw-adapter-p-159.html) and [like these](http://studio-lighting.co.nz/14-and-38-male-threaded-screw-adapter-spigot-p-157.html) are not suitable directly but may give ideas.

Answer (score 2):

How many of these do you need? For a small quantity, it should be straightforward to drill and tap some round brass bar to screw onto the stud on one end and drill the other end to admit a wire with a set screw in the side to hold it in place.

Comment: around 50 or so. and i am more looking for an (almost) off-the-shelf solution that is really reliable, as the connection will have to be opened and closed a couple of times.